# Error: ID3D11Texture2D is not defined.

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I included d3d11.h header, but when I declare a pointer of this type:

```
ID3D11Textrue2D* pDepthStencilBuffer = 0;
```

it says that ID3D11Texture2D is not defined.

So how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Try to add all the tags that could help your question to be found. Also, you should always include your question in the Title. Don't go with something general like "About ID3D11Texture2D" because it gives no clue to the reader what this question is about. I edited your question to improve it and I added the C++ tag. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You've mispelled `ID3D11Textrue2D`, it should be `ID3D11Texture2D`.